# How to use csv writerow to write to one column

Tags: python-3.x, csv, indexing, iteration

Hey all I have a csv file that is 100 columns by 100 rows. I am reading in the rows and storing certain columns as such.

```
module_id = []
mmms_id = []
with open(filename, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        reading = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        for row in reading:
            mmms_id.append(row[19])
            module_id.append(re.findall('MD-\d{1,3}', row[20]))
```

Now I make some changes to these columns I have in the background and want to re insert them into the CSV (in the associated rows) using csv.writer and writerow.

The only way I see doing this is storing all the other 98 columns of data which I do not want to to do. Any thoughts?

Comment: _"Now I make some changes to these columns"_ — are these changes dependent on the other rows?

Comment: Every row needs to stay together. I can't just input the data randomly in, but the data does not depend on one another.

Comment: OK, so if we can assume that your CSV is named `'data.csv'`  your plan could be _a)_ open `'data.csv'` for reading and open a temporay file for writing  _b)_ for every row in `'data.csv'` read the row, compute the mods, write the modded row to the temporary file  _c)_ if everything is OK, rename `'data.csv'` to `'data.bak'` and rename the temporary file to `'data.csv'`.

Comment: What I've described above can be simplified using the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module that handles automagically the temporary file and the backup, but you possibly could prefer to swim nearer to the shore...